# put "request.getRemoteUser" value input

Tags: security, jsp, session, struts2, jaas

I'm looking for something like that in Struts 2 :

```
<s:textfield name="name" value="%{#request.getRemoteUser()}" 
                              label="Evaluateur"  required="true" />
```

this not work and I'm testing

```
<s:textfield name="name" value="<%=request.getRemoteUser()%>"
                              label="Evaluateur"  required="true" />
```

Comment: What is request? Does it have a getRemoteUser() method? If you want something like the first line, why not use the first line? You can't use the second line because you can't evaluate that kind of expression where an OGNL expression is expected.

Comment: Here I m using jaas for security my app and i want to put user conneted in input field with value and  the name of user connected is knowing by this expression  `<%=request.getRemoteUser()%>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a `HttpServletRequest` object in JSP from the action context with `com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletRequest` key or by using static property of `StrutsStatics` interface.

```
<s:textfield value="%{#context[@org.apache.struts2.StrutsStatics@HTTP_REQUEST].getRemoteUser()}"/>
```

Comment: Here i need make some change for respeting my database sechema and get ID of user connected  ,somthing like that : `request.getRemoteUserID`          `<s:textfield value="%{#context[@org.apache.struts2.StrutsStatics@HTTP_REQUEST].getRemoteUserID()}"/>`

Comment: I have Found This  `<s:textfield value="%{#context[@org.apache.struts2.StrutsStatics@HTTP_REQUEST].getRequestedSessionId()}"/>`but the result is crypted like this : C84CA17C048D0A3C5C6171C8C975B3AE